# How to functionally compose Scala's Either

Tags: scala, functional-programming, either

If I have one or more Either values how can I compose them in a functional way so that I can log an error if there is a left value but continue in the function if there is a right value. For example

```
def composeEither(ethr: Either[Error, String]): Either[Error, String] = {
     ethr match { case Left(err) => log.error(err.getMessage) }

     //this obviously will not work but something like map that is right biased         
     ethr map { e => e } //Just for the sake of example - there might be a different either calculated within the map         
}
```

Let me know if there is anything else I can add to make my question more clear.

Comment: You should use `Try` instead of `Either`

Comment: I am using a third party library that returns an Either and I would like to keep the code clean by not arbitrarily converting if I don't have to.

Comment: are you on Scala 2.11 (unbiased Either) or 2.12 (right-biased Either)?

Comment: Unfortunately 2.11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this, maybe:

```
  ether
   .right
   .flatMap(anotherEither(_).right)
   .flatMap(yetAnother(_).right)
   .left
   .map { err => logError(_.getMessage); err }
```